# counting number of characters from input

Tags: c, character, counting, getchar

Below is my code to count number of characters.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int count=0; /*better to initialise a large number */
        int c;
        while(getchar() != EOF)
        {
                count++;
        }
        printf("\nNumber of character seen so far is %d\n",count);
        return 0;

}
```

Input:

```
abcd^D
^D
```

Output seen:

```
Number of character seen so far is 5
```

Output expected:

```
Number of character seen so far is 4
```

after `d` I am entering `^D` to send `EOF` signal. But it is not working there and when I enter new line and send `^D`, `EOF` signal is read.

Am i missing something here? Why the signal is not going through in first case.

Comment: On some environments (typically on Windows, and possibly in some built-in "terminals" of IDE's) you might need to press the `EOF` key-sequence on an empty line by itself, or it wont be registered as such. It's not an error in your program, it's just how your environment works.

Comment: In the case of Windows console, the `Ctrl-Z` must be enclosed by <Enter> keys.

Comment: Suzanno Hogwarts, Print what is read as numbers: `int ch;  while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)  { count++; printf(" %2X", ch);   }` and report output.  I suspect the reason for 5 instead of 4 will become plain.

Comment: You can actually read each character read and print its value as an `int` inside your loop to see what characters do get passed to your program.